# Как правильно реализовать урлы в django?

Tags: python, django

Главный urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
               path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
               path('', include('articles.urls')),  # Главная страница
               path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),  # Редактор
               path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),  # Выход из аккаунта
               path('', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
               path('profile/', include('userprofile.urls')),  # Профиль
               path('likes/', include('likes.urls'))  # Лайки
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

У меня есть приложения `articles`, `profile`, `likes`. В приложении `articles` есть отображении главной страницы, с которой можно перейти в профиль, но, так как путь ' ' расширяется `articles.urls`, то, соответственно, попасть в `profile` невозможно. Как правильно реализовать `urls`, чтобы `django` учитывал и `profile/`? Я пытался уже в `articles.urls` расширить путём `profile`, но мне выдало ошибку:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'userprofile' is not a registered namespace

`userprofile` это `app_name` в урлах.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы работал урл profile его нужно прописать выше главной страницы, так и со всеми

```
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('likes/', include('likes.urls')),  # Лайки
                  path('profile/', include('userprofile.urls')),  # Профиль
                  path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),  # Выход из аккаунта
                  path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),  # Редактор
                  path('', include('articles.urls')),  # Главная страница
                  path('', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                                                                                           document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```